# Class with auto-generated unique incremental integer values for attributes (the same as 'enum.auto()' do)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I need Enum-like style for a class to auto-generate vales. I can not use Enum because I need mutability, in other words, I will need to add attributes at runtime.

Pseudo-code:

```py
def auto(attribute_name: str) -> int:
    # Calculate a value for an attribute...
    # E.g. the first attribute will have "1", the second will have "2", etc.
    return value


class Something:
    foo = auto()  # Must be auto-assigned as 1
    bar = auto()  # Must be auto-assigned as 2
    spam = auto()  # Must be auto-assigned as 3
    eggs = auto()  # Must be auto-assigned as 4


assert Something.foo == 1
assert Something.bar == 2
assert Something.spam == 3
assert Something.eggs == 4

Something.add("new_attribute")
assert Something.new_attribute == 5
```

I want to make sure that I will not reinvent the wheel by writing a lot of custom code. Are the any common ways to solve the issue?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry, my bad. I've updated the question. I do not need instances at all: only class. I even will not initialize it. I will use class only to store attributes with values. Think about my idea like about mutable Enum or like about dictionary with unique auto-generated incremented values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enum.auto` is not actually a counter. It merely produces a sentinel value that is converted to a counter *or similar* by the `enum.Enum` machinery.

While there is no directly re-useable, public variant of this mechanism, it is simple enough to write your own:

```py
auto = object()


class AttributeCounter:
    """Baseclass for classes enumerating `auto` attributes"""
    # called when creating a subclass via `class Name(AttributeCounter):`
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls._counter = 0
        # search through the class and count up `auto` attributes
        for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
            if value is auto:
                cls.add(name)

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, name: str):
        """Add attribute `name` with the next counter value"""
        count = cls._counter = cls._counter + 1
        setattr(cls, name, count)
```

The `auto` value is an arbitrary sentinel for "counted attributes"; if desired one could turn it into a function or even re-use `enum.auto`.

Using `__init_subclass__` is a lightweight alternative to the metaclass magic used by `enum`. [Similar to `enum`'s use of `_generate_next_value_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values), it provides the general machinery but allows overwriting the logic by replacing a single method `add`.

---

Similar to `enum.Enum`, the counter functionality is added to your own types by inheritance:

```py
class Something(AttributeCounter):
    foo = auto
    bar = auto
    spam = auto
    eggs = auto


assert Something.foo == 1
assert Something.bar == 2
assert Something.spam == 3
assert Something.eggs == 4

Something.add("new_attribute")
assert Something.new_attribute == 5
```